# Measure the performance of component rendering with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to measure the time required to render a React component (both the virtual DOM and the HTML DOM) used as a React Router route handler. The measurement obviously should include the time required to render all the child components.

Is it possible to measure it somehow without manually calling the `ReactDOM.render` (to render the component into an HTML element not used by the router)?